# Why is Spatialite delivering "Invalid SRID" error message

Tags: qgis, spatialite, proj, epsg, srid

Qspatialite in QGIS 1.8 (and also Spatialite-gui) delivers an "Invalid SRID" error message when I try to load shapefiles with a SRID value of 3814 (Mississippi Transverse Mercatur).  The SRID is within the database file spatial_ref_sys table.

For troubleshooting purposes I tried loading the shapefiles directly into a blank QGIS session.  QGIS builds its own custom CRS proj4 code and correctly reprojects the shapefiles on the fly against WGS84 Orthophoto (Bing Maps), but it doesn't attribute the projection as EPSG 3813, instead it's called "Custom 100003".  I figured it should find EPSG 3814.  Also, using the QGIS plugin, Qspatialite has a dialog that allows the user to scroll through a list of available projections, using both common and EPSG names, with SRID value listed as well.  SRID 3814 is not listed in dialog, but I double checked and it actually is in the database's spatial_ref_sys table.

Thanks for the user who had helped me discover that the SRID is already in the table, and doesn't need to be added. Can someone help identify the problem here?  It's not getting read.

EDIT: 
Here is the data you requested regarding my prior question (I couldn't copy it into a comment field)

This shapefile correctly reprojects on the fly to WGS 84. EsriShapefile loaded into QGIS 1.8 (Ubuntu 10.04 -- UbuntuGIS Repositories version): USER:100003 - * Generated CRS (`+proj=tmerc +lat_0=32.5 +lon_0=-89.75 +k=0.9998335 +x_0=500000 +y_0=1300000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs`)

myEsriShapefiles.prj ------ `PROJCS["mstm",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",1300000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-89.75],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9998335],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",32.5],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]`

compare this to http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3814/ 3814.prj -----

```
PROJCS["NAD83 / Mississippi TM",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North American Datum 1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Transverse Mercator"],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-89.75],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",32.5],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9998335],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["false_northing",1300000.0],UNIT["m",1.0]]
```

comparison of prj files below: 1>Esri.prj 2>3814.prj (the order of the parameters is different)

```
PROJCS["mstm",GEOGCS PROJCS["NAD83 / Mississippi TM",GEOGCS

["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM ["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM

["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID ["D_North American Datum 1983",SPHEROID

["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]], ["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],

PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"], PROJECTION["Transverse Mercator"],

PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0], PARAMETER["false_easting",500000.0],

PARAMETER["False_Northing",1300000.0], PARAMETER["false_northing",1300000.0],

PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-89.75], PARAMETER["central_meridian",-89.75],

PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9998335], PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9998335],

PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",32.5], PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",32.5],

UNIT["Meter",1.0]] UNIT["m",1.0]]
```

Comment: PS- I could load shapefiles using other common SRID numbers, for instance the one for WGS84.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it depends on the Version of Qgis Lisboa you use.
There is a bug in Qgis standalone installer for Windows which prevents the synchronisation of Qgis own CRS database with that of Gdal, if the installation path contains blanks (which is default). The Osgeo4w Installer does it correct by now, and supplies EPSG:3814 from GDAL to qgis:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=32.5 +lon_0=-89.75 +k=0.9998335 +x_0=500000 +y_0=1300000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

If Qgis is not sure whether the .prj file is identical to a EPSG, it rather creates its own CRS. Missing towgs84 parameters could be a reason. The .prj file contains a WKT formatted CRS definition.

spatialreference.org gives this WKT definition for 3814:

```
PROJCS["NAD83 / Mississippi TM",
GEOGCS["NAD83",
    DATUM["North American Datum 1983",
        SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137.0,298.257222101,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
        TOWGS84[1.0,1.0,-1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.017453292519943295],
    AXIS["Geodetic latitude",NORTH],
    AXIS["Geodetic longitude",EAST],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse Mercator",
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9807"]],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",-89.75],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",32.5],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9998335],
PARAMETER["false_easting",500000.0],
PARAMETER["false_northing",1300000.0],
UNIT["m",1.0],
AXIS["Easting",EAST],
AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","3814"]]
```

The towgs84 parameters differ. EPSG notes 0;0;0 for mainland USA, and 1;1;-1 only for Hawaii.

The EPSG registry at `http://www.epsg-registry.org/` has almost identical values vor EPSG:3813 and 3814.

I'm not sure if qspatialite uses the Qgis CRS database or that of spatialite itself for the input mask.

Can you insert the .prj and qgis made Custom CRS string here?

Comment: I will insert the .prj and qgis CRS in about five hours or so, when I'm back at that computer--It's a Ubuntu 10.04 machine using the UbuntuGIS repositories. The same problem did occur with the standalone Spatialite-GUI as well.  If I specific another SRID number, the shapefiles will load into the database.  That lead me to believe that the problem is with the proj.4 definition in the reference table.  Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: Shapefiles correctly

Comment: This won't allow me to paste into a comment field, but here goes (manual typing)   USER:100003 - * Generated CRS (+proj=tmerc +lat_0=32.5+lon_0=89.75 +k=0.9998335 +x_0=500000 +y_0=1300000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs)                                            ESRI.prj:   PROJCS["mstm",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM ["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM ["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0], [[to be continued next COMMENT]]

Comment: PARAMETER ["False_Northing",1300000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-89.75],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9998335],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",32.5],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

Comment: The prj file lacks the AUTHORITY["EPSG","3814"] at the end, so spatialite has to guess from the values what SRID number it should take. This might go wrong in your case.

Comment: I had no problem importing a sample dataset from http://www.maris.state.ms.us/ with manually selecting SRID:3814 in spatialite_gui 1.5.0. Qgis Master identifys the CRS as 3814, while Qgis 1.8.0 creates a custom CRS.

Comment: My **Spatialite-gui** version is only at **1.2.1** from (Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid) UbuntuGIS Repository.  That version is the same for both the "Stable" and "Unstable" section.  The **Qspatialite plugin** is at **6.0.4.**

Comment: This morning, on Windows 7, I uninstalled and reinstalled QGIS using the OSGeo Live install, and installed everything using Express Method, and selected everything except the mapserver, Apache web install.  Qspatialite plugin is installed but not configured correctly.  It can't even create a proper spatialite database, instead it delivers a lot of error dialog boxes including the dreaded series of errors leading up to "this is an sqlite database: convert to spatialite database?"  then "failed to convert to spatialite".  I have the OsGeo icon to click, which takes me to a DOS command line

Comment: For Windows, you can get a more recent version of spatialite_gui from http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/. I heard that Qspatialite is a bit behind the current development of spatialite. I don't use it, but DB Manager or the gui. I create new spatialite databases with Layer->New->New spatialite layer from inside Qgis.

Comment: I primarily use QGIS with Ubuntu.  The convenience of the UbuntuGIS repositories is great, but I will definitely be building the spatialite_gui 1.5 on Windows7, and if that works will try it on Ubuntu as well.  I will post again to give a progress update, maybe 20 hours from.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: You don't have to build it yourself on Windows 7, there are Windows binaries available on the site (scroll just a bit down, it does not tell you that its the gui ;-) ) By the way, selecting everything in OSGeo44w install is not a good idea. You might get older and dev versions which may interfere with stable ones.

Comment: I downloaded the binary zip file for the gui and am trying to figure out how to install it.  I believe I'm supposed to check and make sure that all it's dependencies are properly configured.  I think I need to do some research to figure out what to do with the binaries.  (I'm trying to do this on Windows 7)  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just extract it once and start the .exe;-)

Comment: Thanks! I had looked for an exe in the download, found none, and thought it was only available to "build".   Just found the zipfile with an executable.  First, to fix my Qspatialite install I'm reinstalling osgeo4w and unchecked GRASS.  It's going to install GIS, GDAL, uDig and OpenEV (I'm not familiar with uDig).  Then I'll run the Spatialite-gui executable, hopefully with the ability to load SRID:3814 shapefiles.  Then I'll check Qspatialite to see if it's configured as well as my Ubuntu version.  I'll give an update in another 8 hours or so.

Comment: early update:  Success--  Spatialite_gui 1.5 loads SRID:3814 shapefile!  Is there a way to load multiple files at once? (Qspatialite can do that).  Should I submit a bug report somewhere for Qspatialite not being able to handle the 3814 EPSG?

Comment: Its not a good idea to install osgeo4w completely. There are many dev and deprecated older versions which might interfere each other. I only select the packages I want. You can submit a bug report for qspatialite here: http://code.google.com/p/qspatialite/issues/list. But I think it only works if the Qgis version knows EPSG:3814, and does not build a custom CRS.

Comment: Is that the advanced install option you use then?  I had used the Express method, then deselected GRASS since, at the moment, don't plan on using it.  QGIS with GDAL 1.9.2 and the ability to use Spatialite and PostGIS were my objectives.  Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, I always use advanced install. The necessary packages are chosen automatically.

Comment: By the way, adding AUTHORITY["EPSG","3814"] to my prj didn't make a difference as far as Qspatialite goes.  I see that Spatialite 4.0.0 was just released yesterday (11/25/2012).  Does Spatialite_Gui require Spatialite or sqlite?

Comment: I was interested to learn a batch method of loading multiple shapfiles (SRID:3814)

Comment: You may try this for a whole folder of shapefiles: 'for %%N in (D:\Karten\shp\\*.shp) DO D:\Karten\spatialite\spatialite_tool -i -shp D:\Karten\shp\%%~nN -d D:\Karten\sqlite\db.sqlite -t %%~nN -c UTF-8'

Comment: Hi, I need help identifying this script code, and how to use it.  Is it spatialite code for the Windows CLI? Also, is there a way to paste text into the CLI, or, I suppose this is meant for a script text file.  I need to check out a tutorial on it to begin.  Thanks @Andre Joost

Comment: Its the content of a bat file for Windows (without the ' '). You have to adopt the paths to the tool and the files. You might try 'D:\Karten\spatialite\spatialite_tool -i -shp D:\Karten\shp\<filename> -d D:\Karten\sqlite\db.sqlite -t <filename> -c UTF-8' first, omitting the .shp in the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Use Spatialite_gui 1.5 or better for loading SRID:3814 shapefiles.  Qspatialite 6.0.4 plugin for QGIS 1.8 (Lisboa)can't handle that EPSG yet.

Comment: Spatialite 4.0.0 was just released yesterday (11/25/2012).  I'm not sure how that inter-operates with Qspatialite or Spatialite_Gui.  But I see in a tutorial that prior versions possible used older Proj.4 SRID values.  "3814" may have been added afterwards; perhaps that's the reason Qspatialite can't figure out what to do with an SRID:3814

Comment: Spatialite_gui was also updated to 1.6.0 on the same day. It contains all necessary files of spatialite 4.0.0 and sqlite. That makes Qspatialite even more behind the development. I guess Qspatialite only looks into the Qgis CRS database for valid SRIDs. You can have the latest GDAL 1.9.2 together with Qgis Lisboa via Osgeo4w installer.